# Postgres: update all values in column by one?

Tags: php, postgresql

Is there a way to do this?  I imagine the following will not work.

UPDATE table SET column = column + 1 ...

Other than writing a function or using PHP, is there a way to do this with a query?

Comment: Your above SQL will work just as you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you try it? It should *just work*.

Answer (score 4):

It'll just work:

```
# psql -U postgres
psql (9.0.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create database test;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \c test
You are now connected to database "test".
test=# create table test (test integer);
CREATE TABLE
test=# insert into test values (1);
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into test values (2);
INSERT 0 1
test=# select * from test;
 test 
------
    1
    2
(2 rows)

test=# update test set test = test + 1;
UPDATE 2
test=# select * from test;
 test 
------
    2
    3
(2 rows)
```